# How to make unit test "location.href" by jest Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

## What I want to do

I wanna make test that is redirect by click.
if possible, I wanna make test not only method called assertion but redirect "URL" assertion.

## Test Target Code

```js
<p class="target" v-on:click="redirect">Click!</p>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    redirect() {
      window.location.href = '/home'
    },
  }
}
```

## Test Code

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import redirectComponent from '../components/RedirectComponent.vue'

describe('Redirect component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(redirectComponent)

  it('Redirect By Click Test', () => {
    wrapper.find('.target').trigger('click');
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/home');
  })
})
```

## result

```
Expected: "/home"
Received: "http://localhost/"
```

How can I make redirect test?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` gives you the URL of the current page;

`window.location.pathname` will give you the path name of the current page, which I believe, is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After changing from href to pathname, I received `/`.  I expect `/home`

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution!

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import redirectComponent from '../components/RedirectComponent.vue'

describe('Redirect component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(redirectComponent)

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {
      href: 'http://localhost',
    },
    configurable: true,
  });

  it('Redirect By Click Test', () => {
    wrapper.find('.target').trigger('click');
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/home');
  })
})
```